# ActionBar is behind the status bar Translucent bars

Tags: android, android-actionbar, translucentdecor

I have a problem implementing the translucent status and navigation bar in Android 4.4...

So, when I enable the translucent status und nav bar, even after declaring FitsSystemWindows and ClipToPadding, even the ActionBar goes behind the Status bar.

Here's my theme, maybe there is an error there:

```
 <style name="Theme.Start" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Start</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when your actionbar contain only a title.

The following work for me

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Be sure to init your actionbar Home button after your setContentView()

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Does it solve your problem?